# Not able to get Cells.Items method of the work sheet object in power shell

Tags: powershell

I need to read cells values from a worksheet and i am referencing the following piece of code, however i don't get `.Items()` method.

Code Referred:

```
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(2,1).Text
```

Also is there any other way we can read the cell values?
Any suggestions/help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Ketan

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of searching, and found the below. If you're just looking to the read the values from the cell, any of the below should work. I was able to return values on them all.

```
$objWorksheet.Range("B1").Text

$objWorksheet.Range("B1:B1").Text

$objWorksheet.Range("B1","B1").Text

$objWorksheet.cells.Item(2, 1).text

$objWorksheet.cells.Item(2, 1).value2

$objWorksheet.Columns.Item(2).Rows.Item(1).Text

$objWorksheet.Rows.Item(1).Columns.Item(2).Text

$objWorksheet.UsedRange.Range("B1").Text
```

This site definately pointed me in the right direction: http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be:

```
$VaribleObject = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item(2, 1).Value()
```

I hope this helps ;)

Reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriram_reddy1/archive/2012/07/16/excel-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Done using same way..still giving error $excelObj = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application" $wrkBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open("FILE_PATH") $wrkShtGroup = $wrkBook.Worksheets.Item(4)                                                          $wrkShtGroup.Cells.Items(2,2).Value()

Comment: Hi that really strange! I dont really use poweshell meself but I fond this that should help! goto page 378. It goes into detail far more than I could as I dont know what code you might have thats effecting the result! hope it helps

Comment: the code iv done is correct, make sure your worksheet is correct? so you have 4 sheets within the workbook and you want to access the fourth? also your accessing row 2, 1 would be the header. the second val is 2 which would be column 2! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriram_reddy1/archive/2012/07/16/excel-with-powershell.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1,2).Value2 = "New Value"
$objWorksheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\Public\test2.xlsx")
```